# Как изменить название дня недели с английского на русский язык?

Tags: php, дата

Как изменить день недели в PHP? Например, **Thursday** на **четверг**.

```
<?php
$date = getdate();
echo 'Сегодня ' . $date[weekday] . '';
?>
```

Этот код выдаёт:

> Сегодня Thursday

Как сделать так, чтобы было:

> Сегодня Вторник

В JavaScript это делается так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = new Date()
    var day = date.getDay()
    var daym = date.getDate()
    if (daym < 10)
        daym = "0" + daym
    var dayarray = new Array("воскресенье", "понедельник", "вторник", "среда", "четверг", "пятница", "суббота")
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = ("Сегодня " + dayarray[day] + "")
});
```

Comment: Вы не поверите, но аналогичным образом. Через массив

Comment: @ArchDemon как?

Comment: @KYRAN а в чем проблема? Вы не знаете, как создавать массив в PHP?

Comment: @Regent нашел ответ спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

в *gnu/linux* при наличии сгенерированной локали *ru_RU.UTF-8* (весьма распространённое явление):

```
<?php
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.UTF-8");
  echo strftime("%A, Месяц: %B, Год: %Y, %d/%m/%Y", time());
?>
```

возвращает:

```
Вторник, Месяц: Июль, Год: 2015, 14/07/2015
```

посмотреть список сгенерированных локалей можно командой (с примером вывода):

```
$ locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
POSIX
```

как видим, локалей, начинающихся с *ru_RU*, нет.

сгенерировать локаль можно с помощью команды:

```
$ sudo locale-gen "ru_RU.UTF-8"
Generating locales...
  ru_RU.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

после её выполнения локаль появилась в списке сгенерированных:

```
$ locale -a | grep ru
ru_RU.utf8
```

почему в этом списке она названа не *ru_RU.UTF-8*, а «некорректно» *ru_RU.utf8*? технически, *utf8* — это псевдоним (*alias*) для *UTF-8*, существует он для обратной совместимости, и ссылаться лучше на основное, «правильное» имя: *UTF-8*.

Answer (score 4):

```
$days = array("Thursday" => "Вторник", ...);
echo 'Сегодня ' . $days[$date[weekday]] . '';
```

Comment: нашел ответ спасибо

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
    /* Установка русской локали */
    setlocale(LC_ALL, 'rus');

    /* понедельник, Месяц: Январь, Год: 2010, 11/01/2010 */
    echo strftime("%A, Месяц: %B, Год: %Y, %d/%m/%Y", time());
?>
```

Для utf-8:

```
echo iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", strftime("%A %d %b. %Y %H:%M"));
```

Comment: этот способ не подходит, если у вас кодировка отличая от cp-1251

Comment: Спасибо бывает так �������, Месяц: ����, Год: 2015, 14/07/2015

Comment: @pavelip нашел ответ спасибо