# Как правильно записывается локаль?

Tags: php, кодировка, дата, локализация

Приветствую. Есть проблема. Хочу вывести месяц с помощью `strftime`.
Но так и не нашел, как правильно указывается русская локаль? Где-то пишут `"russian"`, где-то `"ru_RU"`, где-то `"rus"` . Как вообще ее правильно называть? Перепробовал все три варианта. В случае "russian" и "ru" выводятся знаки вопроса ���� , а в случае `"ru_RU"` выводится July вместо Июль. Файл php в формате `utf-8` без bom. В общем тут 2 вопроса, как правильно указывать название локали? И почему выводится July вместо Июль?

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'russian');
$month = strftime('%B');
echo "Месяц $month " ;
?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Как изменить название дня недели с английского на русский язык?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435595/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%81-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%80%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba)

Comment: так и не понял, как правильно записывается русская локаль?

Comment: На какой системе развернут пхп?

Comment: php на виртуальном open server . операционная система windows 8.1

Comment: @ПавелИгорев, можете взять пример из моего ответа к вопросу, ссылка на который приведена в первом комментарии.

Comment: попробовал как в вашем примере, опять же знаки вопросов. но меня немного другое интересует. как правильно называть локаль? и почему выводятся знаки вопроса (либо название месяца на английском вместо русского)?

Comment: 1. чтобы пользователь получил уведомление о вашем комментарии, упоминайте его явно. 2. знаки вопроса (как я понимаю, в браузере), вероятно, вызваны тем, что либо браузер распознаёт страницу как содержащую текст **не** в кодировке *utf8*, либо вы (сервер) явно указываете иную кодировку для страницы. если это, например, *cp1251*, то используйте эту кодировку в команде: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.CP1251")`

Comment: @ alexanderbarakin  на виртуальном сервере установлено utf-8, в браузере юникод. setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru_RU.CP1251")  выводит July вместо Июль.

Answer (score 1):

Все, разобрался. Проблема в виртуальном сервере open server. Не поддерживает он почему-то русскую локализацию, видимо надо искать другой. Выгрузил на обычный сервер, заработало только с такой локализацией ru_RU.UTF-8 . 
Но так и не удалось выяснить, как правильно записывается локаль?
"russian" "rus" "ru" "ru_RU" или "ru_RU.UTF-8" ? на курсах было записано "russian" и почему-то работало.

Comment: Если речь идет о *nix системах можно выполнить в консоли команду: `locale -a`

Comment: а на виртуальном openserver как проверить? там вроде некуда вводить locale -a